# DATATABLES jQuery.Deferred exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded range

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, datatables, thymeleaf

I have a problem in the code of my program, the idea is to make dynamic tables (columns and data, they can be 3x3 or 7x14k ) and for the pagination I am using datatables.net, the problem is that when the dynamic table is very large the app breaks the pagination and releases me in the console

"caught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Function.se [as find] (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:6529)
"

```
<table id="queryResultTable" class="display">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th th:each="header : ${columnNames}" th:text="${header}"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr th:each="row : ${result}">
    <td th:each="columnName : ${columnNames}" th:text="${row.get(columnName)}"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<script th:inline="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#queryResultTable').DataTable({
      deferRender: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

when they are smaller boards I don't have this problem

what can i do to fix this? ajax??

PS: The order of the folders and the scripts are fine

The idea would be for the page to load fast enough, and not throw this problem when the table is very large,

Comment: I cannot recreate your error using the code in your question. I generated a DataTable of 20 columns and 1,000 rows, with no problem. Does that count as "very large"? It will probably be difficult to help you without a [mre]. (Also, it is very unlikely that your solution would be to use Ajax.)

Comment: Side note (not a solution): You do not need `th:inline="javascript"` in your `<script>` tag, because the JavaScript does not contain any Thymeleaf expressions.

Comment: For clarification: "_the app breaks the pagination _" - My test DataTable does not throw any errors relating to pagination, filtering, or sorting actions.